# UICollectionView spacing is incorrect every other row

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am creating a custom flow layout for a UICollectionView, and I am trying to get the spacing right. Despite setting `minimumLineSpacing = 2` every other line, there is only 1px between each row of images, as can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3f75.jpg). I believe this is because Apple now uses points instead of pixels, but how do you fix this? Here is my code in my CollectionViewController that sets the flow layout:

```
    let screenWidth = self.collectionView?.bounds.size.width
    let flowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 2
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 2

    let totalSpacing = flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing * 4.0
    let imageSize = (screenWidth!-totalSpacing)/4.0

    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: imageSize, height: imageSize)
```

Comment: Have you tested on a device? Sometimes the simulator doesn't draw lines properly depending on the resolution of your monitor.

Comment: I unfortunately can't do that unless there's a way without a developer ID.

Comment: Just tested it on a physical iPhone 6, not in the simulator. This issue is present on the device.

Comment: Well, for one, you're doing `let totalSpacing = flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing * 4.0` but in actuality there's only 3 vertical spaces: one between items 1 and 2, one between items 2 and 3, and the last between items 3 and 4.  

So try doing the following:  

    `let totalSpacing = flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing * 3.0` 

and  

    `let imageSize = (screenWidth!-totalSpacing)/4.0`

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer, not as an edit to the question. You can even then mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of this, but for whatever reason it actually looked worse with the correct spacing at the time. I now do my spacing a little differently, and I found the solution to my problem.

Comment: Thanks. I've seen both on SO, so I wasn't sure which was the accepted method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. If the height of the cell is a repeating float, the spacing between each row will alternate, every other row. For instance, if I want to fit three cells with 2 points spacing between each one, each cell will be 123.6666666667 points wide on an iPhone 6. (An iPhone 6 is 375 points across, leading to the calculation (375-4)/3 = 123.6666666667). If I proceed to use the same value for height as I do width, the last 2/3 of a point will cause the rows' spacing to alternate, as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3f75.jpg).

What I've found is that the cell height does not necessarily have to be an int to fix this; setting it to say 123.5 will solve this problem, but ints of course will also work.